# SSIS - Passing numeric parameter to Execute SQL Task

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, numeric

I'm using an OLE DB connection in an Execute SQL task.  I've mapped the parameters I need as Numeric types in the "Parameter Mapping" section of the SQL task.  What I then want to do is add them together but instead of adding they are being concatenated.  Even though I've set them as Numeric types, they are being dealt with as a string.

For example if I map three parameters with values of 1, 1 and 0 (using ?+?+?).  When I try to add them up I get 110 instead of 2.  If I then cast them as integers (using cast(? as integer)+cast(? as integer)+cast(? as integer)) then I get the desired result and an answer of 2.

So my question is why are these being dealt with as string types when I've supposedly declared them as Numeric in the parameter mappings?

[image]

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: FYI, I'm not trying to add the varchar type in the screen shot :)

Comment: I've never used `numeric`, try `int32` or `long`.

Comment: There is no int32 type.  HEre's a list of what's available: Null
Short, 
Long, 
Float, 
Double, 
Currency, 
variant_bool, 
Decimal, 
Signedchar, 
Byte, 
Ushort, 
Ulong, 
large_integer, 
Ularge_integer, 
Filetime, 
Guid, 
Varchar, 
NVarchar, 
Numeric, 
DBDate, 
DBTime, 
DBTimestamp, 
DB_Varnumeric.

Comment: Also, here is it specifies what the NUMERIC type should be equivalent to.  So I still can't see why it would concatenate rather than add. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-ssis-data-types/

Comment: Crap, sorry, I read parameter and somehow convinced myself you were talking about variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggust that you create a Script task and sum the parameters into a new parameter, which can then be used alone in the SQL Query task.  Alternatively, pass all the parameters to the query without adding them and change the query to do the summation itself.

Are you adding thim in the little scripting pane / window in the SQL Query task? This window is very limited and hard to error check. Much preferable is to limit this to SQL queries (preferably no more than an `EXEC dbo.MyProcedure ?,?,?`) and keep calulations segregated into either a script task or SQL procedure/script.

Comment: Yes, there seem to be multiple ways to skin this cat and I'm ok with that.  I've got it to work.  But I'm really just curious and want to know why it's being dealt with as string values when the parameter is supposed to be Numeric.  e.g. Could it be a bug, or is it just a function of OLE DB works.

Comment: What is the SQLStatement on the task that gives you the result you mentioned?

Comment: I would simply assign to a variable like this [set @myVar = ? + ? + ?;]  The result would be 110 instead of 2.

Comment: hmm, I think basically the problem is that SSIS is converting the text into a sql query by adding the parameters before execution and passing the whole thing as another, altered string to the SQL Server. I guess that it just gets confused trying to make a string by reading a string, inserting values and converting to another string and treats the "+" sign as a concatenation. I have not managed to find any documentation on the specific syntax for this window, so hard to judge whether it is a bug or not. I don't trust it and keep text here to a minimum; using well documented areas where possible